# Merging JSON files using text pad

Tags: json

I am looking to merge two json messages. What I found is that it is a lot more difficult than I thought..
it needs to be parsed and serialized. The new JSON looks nothing like either input JSON file...

Why can't just cut and paste to generate a new JSON file? Do I have to do it programmatically?

Comment: An example would be helpful. What is your merge algorithm. Are you expecting equal keys. If so, how do you want to handle them?

Comment: the issue is that both json message contains hash table with overlapping key values ... it would be nice if json use something that would allow same keys multiple times...

Answer (score 2):

You could try using jQuery's `extend` feature for merging two (or however many json messages). The syntax for merging your two messages and saving the result to a new object would be: 
`var both = jQuery.extend({},json_object_one,json_object_two);`
`both` will now store the merged json message. This is far simpler than merging the file by hand in a text editor. For more on this method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/  
EDIT:
Actually you're going to want to do `var both = jQuery.extend(true,{},obj_one,obj_two);`. The `true` flag turns on deep copy, which will recursively merge any inner objects in the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by hand since [json](http://www.json.org/) is only plain javascript after if you have an insane amount to process doing it programmatically would help.

Answer (score 0):

Example messages would be helpful.  If both represent the same data set then cut and paste should be fine.

You can format the JSON at [JSON Format](http://jsonformat.com/) and that may make your job easier.